# Reading date from oracle database and converting it to datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dataReader["Date"].ToString());
```

I am using this command to read the data from the database but the output dt will be like this
`/Date(1655788824000)/`. Any workaround to get the date in a date format.
I am using .NET Framework

This is the result i am getting : `/Date(1655788824000)/`

Answer (score 0):

I assume is the ticks `1655788824000`.
You can do the following:

`String test = dt.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss.ff", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);`
where `"MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss.ff"` - [Format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings), [DateTimeFormatInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo?view=netframework-4.8)

output: `January 02, 0001 09:59:38.88`

Comment: I have used this method. It works but I need it in date format instead of a string

Comment: the DateTime object actually just stores the number of ticks (100 nanosecond units) since midnight on January 1st of 0001 Common Era. 
[more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

PS: Also, maybe dataReader has a [GetDateTime method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.getdatetime?view=netframework-4.8)
`dataReader.GetDateTime(dataReader.GetOrdinal("Date"))`

Comment: Anyway I can get the value in a proper date format instead of getting the number of ticks or string format ?